# MySQL union with different columns on return

Tags: mysql

Let's look at my query:

```
SELECT count(*) as 'b13' 
FROM `betmatches` 
WHERE `user`='1' AND `mId`='2326' and `odd`='odd2' 
union all 
SELECT count(*) as 'b14' 
FROM `betmatches` 
WHERE `user`='1' AND `mId`='2328' and `odd`='odd2'
```

this is the result when that query runs
array (size=2)

```
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'b13' => string '2' (length=1)
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'b13' => string '1' (length=1)
```

there is 2 b13, but I want to have one `b13` and one `b14` to give me count of each select. is there any solutions?

Comment: UNIONs use the column names from the first query; it wouldn't make much sense to have a column name change part way through a result set.

Comment: so is there any solutions? @Uueerdo

Comment: There is no way to produce the result you are looking for using union. Period. You can use alternative solutions to indicate which query is the source for a given record in a union, but their results will be different from what you ask for.

Comment: I'm not forced to use union, if there is any solution, i'll be thankful you share it with me :) @shadow

Comment: Execute the 2 queries separately, not in a union.

Comment: in php `$mysqli->multi_query` will help me but it's really slow ! cause php run those queries one by one !

Comment: It is confusing if you solved this or not based on all the comments here and there plus your accepted dupe by you

Comment: I used `SELECT IF(count(*) = 1,1,0) as valid,'14' bId FROM betmatches...` and it works, I found something like that in dup @drew

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this :

```
SELECT (SELECT count(*) 
FROM `betmatches` 
WHERE `user`='1' AND `mId`='2326' and `odd`='odd2' 
) as 'b13' ,
(SELECT count(*) 
FROM `betmatches` 
WHERE `user`='1' AND `mId`='2328' and `odd`='odd2'
) as 'b14'
```

Comment: this is not working

ERR#1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as 'b13',(SELECT count(*) FROM `betmatches` WHERE `user`='1' AND `mId`='2328' an' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

Use an extra column:

```
SELECT COUNT(*), label as 'b13' 
FROM betmatches 
WHERE user='1' AND mId='2326' and odd='odd2' 
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*), label as 'b14' 
FROM betmatches
WHERE user='1' AND mId='2328' and odd='odd2'
```

A column in a MySQL result set has only one alias, so your current approach won't work.

Comment: I've test it, but same result !`array (size=2)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'count(*)' => string '2' (length=1)
      'b13' => null
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'count(*)' => string '1' (length=1)
      'b13' => null`